# Mail Merge IF Statement works but I have to manually "Update the Merge Field"

Tags: mail-merge

I run my mail merge and the output in the Word Document appears to be blank. I right click where the output should be and select Update Field. I can then see the result so the IF Statement is working but is hiding the result from view.
Any thoughts on how I can make it automatically update?
There's no issue with the other merge fields
IF Statement is:

```
{IF "{MERGEFIELD OPPORTUNITY_PREFIX}"="1300" "YES" "NO"}
```

Cheers John

Comment: You could look at using a 3rd party tool such as Drawloop or Conga to do the merge for you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation it looks like MS Word does not automatically update all merge fields. :-(

"Remember that Word is a word processor and not a spreadsheet. Unlike Excel and other spreadsheet applications, most fields used in Word will not be updated automatically simply by changing a variable. In fact, some fields don't update at all without specific user action. "

Looks like it's back to the drawing board.
Cheers John